# How to select and group fortnightly in postgreql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to group the rows in a table fortnightly, but can't seem to work out how to do it - especially, as the `date_part` function does not have a 'fortnight' keyword argument.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
                   dt       DATE NOT NULL,
                   f1       REAL NOT NULL,
                   f2       REAL NOT NULL,
                   f3       REAL NOT NULL,
                   f4       REAL NOT NULL
                );



SELECT AVG((f1+f2+f3+f4)/4) as fld_avg FROM
(   
    SELECT date_part('year', dt) AS year_part, 
       date_part('fortnight',  dt) AS fortnight_part,
       f1, f2, f3, f4
    FROM foo
    WHERE dt >= date_trunc('day', NOW() - '3 month')
) foo
GROUP BY year_part, fortnight_part
```

How may I rewrite (or modify) the query above so as to group data fortnightly?

Comment: Add a Calendar table with with dates, week numbers, fortnights, etc. All you have to do is join to it and group by year, fortnight taking full advantage of indexing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos could you please demonstrate this with a trivial example? It's hard to follow otherwise, I'm not a DB person by profession.

Comment: You could generalize your question for arbitrarily intervals, not just fortnights, and simply use fortnight as an example. This way, your question would be useful for more people.

Comment: I answered again :) with eplanation why my first attempt with even/odds would fail, how you can "inverse" it to still make it neat and smart and why it  would still be limited and finally the working query, which Is a simple join on hand made two week interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic idea

What we need to do, is take intervals of 14 consecutive days and map them to unique buckets and then group by those buckets. These buckets can of any type, `int`, `char`, `timstamp`, as long as we have unique value.

### Division

A simple way to accomplish this is division. Divide by 14 days and truncate the result to date precision.

For example, we can extract the number of seconds since 1970-01-01, the UNIX epoch, and divide by the number of seconds in a fortnight: `14 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 14 * 86400 = 1209600`. (I'll use Vao Tsun's example data)

```
WITH c(d) AS (values('2017.12.21'::date),('2017.12.31'),('2018.01.26'),('2018.02.01'))
SELECT (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM d)::int/86400)/14 fortnight FROM c
```

which yields fortnights since 1970-01-01 (a Thursday):

```
 fortnight
-----------
      1251
      1252
      1254
      1254
(4 rows)
```

The integer values we get, represent the number of fortnights since 1970-01-01, but we don't have to care about this. The important thing is, that it uniquely identifies a fortnight.

Due to 1970-01-01 being a Thursday, all fortnights will start at a Thursday. We might want to vary the starting point of our fortnight to a different day of the week (e.g. Monday) by adding:

```
WITH c(d) AS (values('2017.12.21'::date),('2017.12.31'),('2018.01.26'),('2018.02.01'))
SELECT (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM d)::int/86400 + 4)/14 fortnight FROM c
```

By adding four days to Thursday we end up at Monday.

If you rather want fortnights with respect to the beginning of the year, instead of some arbitrary absolute date, such as 1970-01-01, we can use the day of the year instead:

```
WITH c(d) AS (values('2017.12.21'::date),('2017.12.31'),('2018.01.26'),('2018.02.01'))
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM d) * 26 + EXTRACT(doy FROM d)::int/14 AS fortnight FROM c;
```

which yields

```
 fortnight
-----------
     52467
     52468
     52469
     52470
(4 rows)
```

We need to multiply the extracted year by 26, because there are 26.1… fortnights in a year.

### Truncation

Instead of division another approach is truncation. We map each day of a specific fortnight to the first timestamp of that fortnight.

```
WITH c(d) AS (values('2017.12.21'::date),('2017.12.31'),('2018.01.26'),('2018.02.01'))
SELECT d - make_interval(secs => EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM d)::int % (86400 * 14)) AS fortnight FROM c;
```

which yields

```
      fortnight
---------------------
 2017-12-14 00:00:00
 2017-12-28 00:00:00
 2018-01-25 00:00:00
 2018-01-25 00:00:00
(4 rows)
```

This might seems a bit more complicated, but has some benefits. The result is still a date/time type and other code does not need to worry about the fact, that we used fortnights.

Again, instead of absolute fortnights, we can calculate this with respect to the beginning of the year:

```
WITH c(d) AS (values('2017.12.21'::date),('2017.12.31'),('2018.01.26'),('2018.02.01'))
SELECT d - make_interval(days => EXTRACT(dow FROM d)::int % 14) AS fortnight FROM c;
```

which yields

```
      fortnight
---------------------
 2017-12-17 00:00:00
 2017-12-31 00:00:00
 2018-01-21 00:00:00
 2018-01-28 00:00:00
(4 rows)
```

The result is of type `timestamp`, you might want to have `date` instead. This can be addressed by casting:

```
(d - make_interval(days => EXTRACT(dow FROM d)::int % 14))::date
```

or subtracting `int` instead of `interval` from `date`:

```
d - (EXTRACT(dow FROM d)::int % 14)
```

There are much more possibilities. With this scheme, we can calculate the fortnight or any other interval with respect to the beginning of the month, some arbitrary date, etc.

Comment: This is easier to understand (and hence modify) - and it's likely to be the answer I'll end up accepting. I just need to make sure I fully understand it before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

**update** 
fortnight is a two week period - one even the other odd. eg week 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6.

closer: 2 is even, `mod(2,2)=0` and 1 is odd, `mod(1,2)=1`

4 is even, `mod(4,2)=0` and 3 is odd, `mod(3,2)=1`

6 is even, `mod(6,2)=0` and 5 is odd, `mod(5,2)=1`

thus you can make an assumption that each one week's in year consecutive number divided by two reminder is `1`, and each next one weeks number/2 reminders `0`

The general idea is - using the sequential number of week in a year. To avoid Jan 1st to be first and Dec31 (possible be the 53rd - and thus two odds in a row), I use `IW`

> week number of ISO 8601 week-numbering year (01-53; the first Thursday
>   of the year is in week 1)

then I assume that if one week number will be odd, next will be even, so we divide all the time in parts of two weeks - even+odd.

SQL Example:

```
o=# with c(d) as (values('2017.12.21'::date),('2017.12.31'),('2018.01.26'),('2018.02.01'))
select d,to_char(d,'IW'),right(to_char(d,'IW'),1)::int,mod(right(to_char(d,'IW'),1)::int, 2) from c;
     d      | to_char | right | mod
------------+---------+-------+-----
 2017-12-21 | 51      |     1 |   1
 2017-12-31 | 52      |     2 |   0
 2018-01-26 | 04      |     4 |   0
 2018-02-01 | 05      |     5 |   1
(4 rows)
```

mod is either 0 or 1 - group by this column

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Of course you would need to add `outer join` on `generate_series` if you want data without gaps...

Comment: Apologies for showing my ignorance here, but database foo is the weakest tool in my IT arsenal, and I simply do not understand your answer. Could you possibly make it slightly more easy to understand for mere mortals?

Comment: I'm voting it up as I appreciate your effort in answering the question - and it seems an elegant solution. It is still quite terse for my understanding - I'm having to go through it slowly to grok

Answer (score 0):

I post another answer to explain how I was wrong and why my "smart-n-neat"
way failed...

the schema build and queries are at:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j5i2Td8CvxCVXQQYePKzCe/0

the first (and correct) query:

```
select distinct w2, avg(c) over (partition by w2)
from d
join generate_series('2016.11.28'::date,'2017.02.23'::date,'2 weeks'::interval) w2
  on gs >= w2 and gs < w2 + '2 weeks'::interval
order by w2;
```

Is a long, simple and correct approach. with idea is to join on two weeks interval. It's working, reliable and all good.

Now the second query:

```
select distinct div(to_char(gs,'IW')::int,2), min(gs) over w, avg(c) over w 
from d
window w as (partition by div(to_char(gs,'IW')::int,2)) 
order by min;
```

Is much shorter, neater and smarter, yet has a huge limitation and is unusable. Here's why:
My approach splits next to last two-weeks-interval to two parts: last week of 2016 and first week of 2017, thus dividing the result by half. If you multiply a sum of averages for those two weeks by a half, the result for both queries will match. Alas introducing `CASE WHEN` logic for the edge year weeks makes neat solution a heavy and overhead. And thus the very point is lost.

**TL;DR** the neat and lightweight solution works only on interval of one year, farther then two weeks from end or start of the year and lastly if our fortnightly interval starts from Monday.

Now the idea behind lightweight solution: `round(2/2, 0)=1` and `round(3/2, 0)=1`, so you can divide year in intervals of two weeks and use it for grouping by.

Also I deliberately took not this New Year switch, because this 2018 Jan 1 is Monday, so `IW` is same as `WW` - which usually is not the case.

Lastly my first answer with odd and even weeks is not viable at all. It divides year not in two-weeks interval, but rather in two parts - for even and odd weeks... I deceived myself with "something close" idea and worked on the reminder, while I should do the opposite the whole value of division...